# Display PDF file in LocalState folder in Windows 8 app in Cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, pdf, winjs

My application downloads a PDF and stores it in the LocalState folder for my Windows 8 app.

I have a link within the app that I would like to show the PDF when the user clicks it.

I've tried displaying it using `ms-appdata:///local/pdfs/filename.pdf` in a `window.open` call and I also tried using the InAppBrowser plugin within cordova with no luck. Additionally, I've tried the following:

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appdata:///local/pdfs/filename.pdf');
var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file).done();
```

I know the file exists as I'm getting a file result back. Just not sure how to allow the user to view it.

Answer (score 2):

By design, the local appdata folder on Windows is accessible only to that app, or to full-trust desktop applications (and this is probably true of similar sandboxed locations on other platforms). As a result, a Windows Store app that gets launched with Launcher.launchFileAsync won't be able access that location (nor can a webview process, which is also sandboxed). If a desktop application gets launched, on the other hand, it probably can access the file, but you can't tell ahead of time if that's the case. Bottom line is that local appdata isn't a good location for letting other apps get at the file.

You'll need to save the file in another location that is accessible to other apps. There are two approaches here, both of which will require a little user interaction to select a location, so they can place the PDFs anywhere they want:

1. Have the user select a save folder for your app, which they can do once. You would invoke the [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) for this purpose, and save the selected folder in the [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx). This way you can have the user select the save folder, which grants you consent to save there, and by saving it in the FutureAccessList you can retrieve it in subsequent sessions without having to ask the user again. Refer to the [File Picker Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba) and the [File Access Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) for more.
2. Have the user select a save location for each individual file, using the FilePicker (see the same sample), and you can also use the access cache to save permissions to those individual locations if you need them later.

There might be Cordova plugins that work with these APIs too, but I haven't checked. Either way, once the file is in an accessible location, launching the file should work just fine.

As an alternate solution, you could consider rendering the PDFs directly in your app. Windows has an API for this in [Windows.Data.Pdf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.data.pdf.aspx), with an [associated sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-showcase-sample-39ced1e8). There might be a plugin or other JS libraries that could also work for this.